# How can I make my animation transition smoothly?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am trying to make an animation of a panel attached with two string though a nail swing from left to right like a pendulum. Here is the animation code and transition function. For the demo, you can check the snippet below:

```css
.headline {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.headline .box {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: -70px;
}

.headline .box:after {
  content: "";
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -85px;
  left: 105px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.headline .panel {
  background: white;
  color: #ff004f;
  font-size: 46px;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  max-width: 250px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 46px;
  position: relative;
}

.headline .panel:hover {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.120, 0.485, 0.950, 0.475);
  animation: pendulum 2s infinite;
}

.headline .panel:before {
  content: "";
  width: 155px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(8px) rotate(148deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.headline .panel:after {
  content: "";
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-10px) rotate(-148deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  right: -18px;
}

@keyframes pendulum {
  0%,
  50%,
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin: 50% -50%;
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
    transform-origin: 50% -50%;
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    transform-origin: 50% -50%;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <div class="box">
    <span class="panel">Test Panel</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

It worked somehow but the animation is robotic and not very smooth and natural. Could you please point out how to improve this animation.

I also can use jQuery for this case if you need to use JS.

Comment: Add "animation: all infinite;" right below your @keyframe, you may want to improove the loop though. Just updated: https://jsfiddle.net/ns1carpp/1/

Comment: Thank Paulo! It didn't work as expected, you can see it had a glitch between each frame, it stopped and continued

Comment: i'm glad somebody else could help you better, I'm new to CSS animations also, I would also suggest that you run your final CSS file in http://autoprefixer.github.io/ for old/cross-browser support since it's using flex and other functions that may vary from browser to browser.

Comment: Nice tool! Thank for your help! But currently we don't support the old browsers so I don't need to care much about this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to @Kushtrim's answer, but I have added a negative `animation-delay` so that the pendulum starts swinging from the bottom, rather than suddenly jumping to `-25deg`. Using this technique it is possible to start an animation mid way. Here are the relevant modified rules:

```
.headline .panel:hover {
      animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.120, 0.485, 0.950, 0.475);
      animation: pendulum 2s infinite; 
      animation-delay: -1.3s /* I added this */
}

@keyframes pendulum {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
    transform-origin: 50% -50%; 
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    transform-origin: 50% -50%; 
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
    transform-origin: 50% -50%; 
  } 
}
```

And a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/125wps7s/

The `animation-delay` time requires trial and error to get right. I just picked a value that seemed close enough.

Comment: My pleasure. I have never had an opportunity to us negative `animation-delay` values before, so I learned something new too :)

Comment: thanks for using negative `animation-delay`. I needed it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Out

```
headline {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.headline .box {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: -70px;
}

.headline .box:after {
  content: "";
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -85px;
  left: 105px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.headline .panel {
  background: white;
  color: #ff004f;
  font-size: 46px;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  max-width: 250px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 46px;
  position: relative;
}

.headline .panel:hover {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.120, 0.485, 0.950, 0.475);
  animation: pendulum 2s infinite;
}

.headline .panel:before {
  content: "";
  width: 155px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(8px) rotate(148deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.headline .panel:after {
  content: "";
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-10px) rotate(-148deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  right: -18px;
}

@keyframes pendulum {
animation: all infinite;
  0%{
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
    transform-origin: 50% -50%;
  }
  50%{
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    transform-origin: 50% -50%;
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
    transform-origin: 50% -50%;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```css
.headline {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.headline .box {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: -70px;
}

.headline .box:after {
  content: "";
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -85px;
  left: 105px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.headline .panel {
  background: white;
  color: #ff004f;
  font-size: 46px;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  max-width: 250px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 46px;
  position: relative;
}

.headline .panel:hover {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.120, 0.485, 0.950, 0.475);
  animation: pendulum 2s infinite;
}

.headline .panel:before {
  content: "";
  width: 155px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(8px) rotate(148deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.headline .panel:after {
  content: "";
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-10px) rotate(-148deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  right: -18px;
}

@keyframes pendulum {
  0%{
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
    transform-origin: 50% -50%;
  }
  50%{
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    transform-origin: 50% -50%;
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
    transform-origin: 50% -50%;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <div class="box">
    <span class="panel">Test Panel</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is smoother than mine but may we start the animation at center point, go up left and move from left to up right. Your animation is starting from left and go to right.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.headline {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        margin-top: 150px;
    }

    .headline .box {
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        left: -70px;
    }

    .headline .box:after {
        content: "";
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        background: black;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 50%;
        top: -85px;
        left: 105px;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .headline .panel {
        background: white;
        color: #ff004f;
        font-size: 46px;
        font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
        padding: 10px;
        font-weight: 700;
        max-width: 250px;
        display: block;
        line-height: 46px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .headline .panel:hover {
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.97, 0.96, 0.01, 0.01);
        animation: pendulum 3s infinite;
        -webkit-transition: 15s;
    }

    .headline .panel:before {
        content: "";
        width: 155px;
        height: 10px;
        background: white;
        display: block;
        transform: translateX(8px) rotate(148deg);
        position: absolute;
        top: -40px;
        left: -16px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .headline .panel:after {
        content: "";
        width: 150px;
        height: 10px;
        background: white;
        display: block;
        transform: translateX(-10px) rotate(-148deg);
        position: absolute;
        top: -40px;
        right: -18px;
    }

    @keyframes pendulum {
        0%{
            transform: rotate(-25deg);
            transform-origin: 50% -50%;
        }
        50%{
            transform: rotate(25deg);
            transform-origin: 50% -50%;
        }
        100%{
            transform: rotate(-25deg);
            transform-origin: 50% -50%;
        }
    }

    body {
        background-color: #EEE;
    }
```

```html
<div class="headline">
    <div class="box">
        <span class="panel">Test Panel</span>
    </div>
</div>
```